# Excel VBA Show/Hide worksheet rows based on cell values in table

Tags: excel, vba

On Sheet13, I have 7 Groupings that I want to be able to show/hide based on whether a table is on another sheet has certain information contained i.e. if "Location" is found in the table (Table18) then I want the associated Grouping on Sheet 13 to unhide that Grouping.

I know that the following work independantly to show and hide the Groupings:

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(24).ShowDetail = True
ActiveSheet.Rows(24).ShowDetail = False
```

So I have tried to incorporate some of that into the code.

Thanks to another stackoverflow user, I'm already using a similar macro to show/hide associated sheets and I have tried to amend that code for this purpose.

The code I am trying is as follows but when I try to run it, it selects the second Sub and gives the error "Compile Error. User defined type not defined".

```
Sub ShowHideGrouping()
'Both Subs work to hide and show Grouping Rows on Sheet18 which are associated to selections made in Table18 of Assumptions worksheet.
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table18")
    Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
    Set rng2 = tbl.ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange

    'Sheet13 is where the Groupings are located and the Rows mentioned are the ones I need to target to unhide that group.
    Call ShowGroupIfFindValue(rng, 1, Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(24))
    Call ShowGroupIfFindValue(rng, 2, Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(46))
    Call ShowGroupIfFindValue(rng, 3, Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(68))
    Call ShowGroupIfFindValue(rng, 3, Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(90))
    Call ShowGroupIfFindValue(rng2, "Business Division", Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(112))
    Call ShowGroupIfFindValue(rng2, "Complexity", Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(134))
    Call ShowGroupIfFindValue(rng2, "Location", Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(156))
End Sub

Private Sub ShowGroupIfFindValue(Look_In As Range, Look_for As Variant, Show_Group As Rows)
    Show_Group.ShowDetail = Not WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Look_In, Look_for) < 1
End Sub
```

Comment: `Rows(24)` returns a `Row`. `Rows` is a collection of rows. Try declaring  `Show_Group As Row`. or `As Range` and use `Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(24).EntireRow` in the `Call`.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks, it compiles now. However, it is throwing an error on `Call ShowGroupIfFindValue(rng, 1, Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(24))`. I changed it to `Call ShowGroupIfFindValue(rng, 1, Sheets("Sheet13").Range("B24"))` but still getting an error "Runtime Error 9: Subscript out of range". I tried adding `.EnireRow` too but same issue.

Comment: What from the two above suggestion declarations did you choose? `As Row` or `As Range`? You should use `.EntireRow` only in case of `As Range` declaration... Then, (not related to the error) you should avoid using `Call`. The simpler VBA way to call a sub is as `ShowGroupIfFindValue rng, 1, Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(24).EntireRow`, for the case of `As Range` declaration in the called `Sub`. `As Row` looks to have more meanings if you have a lot of references (as I have in my testing workbook)...

Comment: I used `Call ShowGroupIfFindValue(rng, 1, Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(24).EntireRow)` but no luck, still has an error.  I also tried removing `Call` and just having `ShowGroupIfFindValue rng, 1, Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(24).EntireRow` but this also doesn't work.

Comment: I clearly asked **"What from the two above suggested declarations did you choose? `As Row` or `As Range`?""**...

Comment: I've used As Range

Comment: Then, try using `Sheets(Sheet13).Range("A24").EntireRow` instead of `ShowGroupIfFindValue rng, 1, Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(24).EntireRow`. I do not have any grouped ranges to test. I am only trying to reproduce `ActiveSheet.Rows(24).ShowDetail = True`, which you confirmed that works... On which code line is the error raised? And which is its description?

Comment: After using `Sheets(Sheet13).Range("A24").EntireRow` I get the following error:  Run-time error '13'. Type Mismatch.  I do appreciate your help so far.

Comment: Using `Sheets(Sheet13).Range("A24")` looks strange. Is `Sheet13` as string variable? If the sheet name, you should use `Sheets("Sheet13").Range("A24")`. Between double quotes...

Answer (score 0):

The Rows property returns a Range, change the "Show_Group As Rows" to "Show_Group As Range".

Comment: Thanks, it compiles now.  However, it is throwing an error on `Call ShowGroupIfFindValue(rng, 1, Sheets(Sheet13).Rows(24))`.  I changed it to `Call ShowGroupIfFindValue(rng, 1, Sheets("Sheet13").Range("B24"))` but still getting an error "Runtime Error 9: Subscript out of range".  Any ideas?